# Cannot evaluate module react-native-gmaps : Configuration with name 'default' not found

Tags: android, reactjs, gradle, react-native

When Gradle compiling react-native-gmaps package it gives error

A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.

> Cannot evaluate module react-native-gmaps : Configuration with name 'default' not found.

[image: error]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a problem with the project settings.gradle file project dir location,
It should be correctly pointed to the project building directory,
eg.,

```
project(':react-native-gmaps').projectDir = new File(rootProject.projectDir, '../node_modules/react-native-gmaps/android/app')
```